# Document signing failed using Fineuploader to make amazon s3 uploads

Tags: php, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

I successfully tested uploading to local server using traditional PHP.
However, I am having problem uploading to Amazon s3.

I wrote php using git examples as reference.Please tell me what am I doing wrong.
All the scripts referenced are in the proper location in my local system and I am not making any CORS requests either.

Here are the specific code sections:

//UI Instance

```
var s3uploader = new qq.s3.FineUploader({

request: {
endpoint: "bucket.s3.amazonaws.com",
accessKey: "given key"
},
signature: {
endpoint: "endpoint.php"
},
uploadSucess: {
endpoint: "endpoint.php?success"
},
});
```

In endpoint.php I have assigned clientPrivateKey,bucketName and hostName and I am assuming that rest of the things are best left untouched. (including composer.json file)

Errors:
1.Error attempting to parse signature 
2.Recieved an empty or invalid server response 
3.Policy signing failed

Further:
Are policy documents to be authored explicitly by ourselves?
How do I know if my bucket supports only version 4 signature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must include include values for the following variables:

- $clientPrivateKey = $_ENV['AWS_CLIENT_SECRET_KEY'];
- $serverPublicKey = $_ENV['AWS_SERVER_PUBLIC_KEY'];
- $serverPrivateKey = $_ENV['AWS_SERVER_PRIVATE_KEY'];
- $expectedBucketName = $_ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'];

Additionally, if you are utilizing v4 signatures, you must also include a value for:

- $expectedHostName = $_ENV['S3_HOST_NAME'];

If you are seeing signature errors, then either you have not set all of these values, or the AWS keys are incorrect.

Regarding your other two questions:

> Are policy documents to be authored explicitly by ourselves?

No, Fine Uploader S3 creates these. Note that policy documents are *only* used for non-chunked uploads. For chunked uploads, the S3 multipart upload API is used, and your signature server is asked to sign a string of identifying headers instead.

> How do I know if my bucket supports only version 4 signature?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region

Comment: I have directly used the keys in code. Setting user environment variables and echoing them using $_ENV or getenv() showed blank.   However since I am not using delete feature I gather that server public and server private keys aren't required. When I am testing from my local machine what should the expected host name be?

Comment: host name of the S3 bucket

Comment: After doing everything, double checking aws credential keys I am getting the same error. Can I send you the code for a quick review?